# time derivative of vector field using lie derivative

Tags: differential-geometry

Is it possible to take "proper" time derivative of vector field $V\in T_{c(t)}M$, along a curve $c(t)$, using lie derivative?

I would like to see something similar to covariant derivative:

$\frac{D V}{dt}=\nabla_{\dot{c}(t)}V$

Or am I missing something?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. The covariant derivative $(\nabla_X Y)(p)$ at a point $p$ depends only on the tangent vector $X(p) \in T_pM$ and on the value of the vector field $Y$ along some curve $c$ which passes through $p$ with velocity $X(p)$. This is crucial property that enables us to define the notion of a covariant derivative of a vector field along a curve.

On the other hand, the Lie derivative $L_X(Y)(p) = [X,Y](p)$ at a point $p$ depends on the values of both $X,Y$ on a neighborhood of $p$. In more fancy terms, it is not $C^{\infty}$-linear with respect to $X$. More precisely, if you look at the definition

$$ [X,Y](p) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\left( d\varphi^X_{t}|_{p} \right)^{-1}(Y(\varphi^X_t(p))) - Y(p)}{t} $$

you see that this depends on the value of $Y$ along an integral curve of $X$ and the differential of the flow of $X$. We use the differential $d\varphi^X_{t}|_{p}$ to identify between the tangents spaces $T_{\varphi^X_t(p)}$ and $T_pM$ so that we can subtract the vectors. In order to know the differential, we must know the flow of $X$ in a neighborhood of $p$ and for that we need to know the vector field $X$ in a neighborhood of $p$. It is not enough to know the values of $X$ along the integral curve.